# .replaceWith() working only once

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to implement a system of reputation of users in my site. So you can see the rep number after the name of the user every time he interacts (for example, every time he makes a comment). There is also a voting system which also alters the reputation of the user and I want the rep number to reflect that change. So I am calling a file through ajax which returns the new rep number for that user. The html/php file is something like this the first instance (if he makes a post):

```
echo '<div class="rep_user_id" id="rep_user_id_'.$posts_row['userid'].'"> '.$posts_row['user_rep'].'</div>';
```

and then (if he makes a comment):

```
echo '<div class="rep_user_id" id="rep_user_id_'.$com_row['userid'].'">'.$com_row['user_rep'].'</div>';
```

both give me this:

```
<div class="rep_user_id" id="rep_user_id_110">293</div>
```

Then the js:

```
function change_reps() {
var userid = $('.rep_user_id').attr('id').replace('rep_user_id_','');
$.ajax({
 url: "vote/get_reputation.php",
 data: "userid="+userid,
 success: function(server_response){
 $("body").ajaxComplete(function(event, request){
   var reputation = server_response;
   $('#rep_user_id_'+userid).replaceWith(''+reputation);
   $('#rep_user_id_'+userid).effect("highlight", {color:'red'}, 1000);
 });  } });  }
```

This function is called after success of another ajax (to update rep and votes). So, from this, what's working: once I click in any arrow up or down I can see the voting counter up or down but I only see the user rep change the very first instance only (post). Why is it changing only once and not throughout the whole document? Has anything to do that the comments section is called from another file (with an include)? FYI the effect works in all instances!
Hope you can help. Thanks

**EDIT:** Since I have seen that I didn't explain myself very well I am adding a few more lines. The issue is that I can't modify multiple elements with the same id and class just one time (as opposed to change one element multiple times). So I have 293 many times throughout the page but the code posted is changing only one element!
This is what triggers change_reps():

```
$("body").on("click", ".vote_com_up", function(){
   var com_id = $(this).attr('id').replace('vote_com_up_','');
   $.ajax({ 
    url: "vote/comment_vote.php",
    data: "com_action=2&com_id="+com_id,
    success: function(server_response){
    $(".vote_com_number").ajaxComplete(function(event, request){
     if(server_response == 'voted')
       { alert("Ya has votado en este post!");}
    else{
       var new_com_votes = server_response; 
       $("#vote_com_number_"+com_id).html(+new_com_votes);
    } }); } 
   }).done(function() {
    change_reps();
   });
   return false;
 });
```

I made a small jsfiddle to show what I want:

http://jsfiddle.net/CMgYb/1/

**SOLUTION:** Bryan Naegele was right: I needed classes instead of ids.

Comment: sounds like stackoverflow :) just refactor their code

Comment: Can you post more code?  What is calling change_reps()?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably has something to do with the fact that you are selecting an ID which will grab the first occurrence of that ID.  You need to use classes.

Answer (score 13):

You're accessing this element by **id**, then *replacing it* with something new.  The only way this'll work a second time is if what you replace it with has the same id as it did before; I'm guessing it does not.

Are you sure you don't want to set the **content** of this element with the `html` function:

```
$('#rep_user_id_' + userid).html('' + reputation);
```

**EDIT**

Looking more closely at your PHP, it does look like you've coded this up to actually replace the entire div.  Still though, I would recommend against coding your PHP to generate the correct element IDs.  Consider trimming this PHP down so that you're just sending the **content** of the div.  Then you can much more simply use `html` like above.

Comment: .html(); was the only solution that worked for me. neither .replaceWith() nor .text() worked.

Answer (score 5):

According to the jQuery docs :

`The .replaceWith() method removes content from the DOM and inserts new content in its place with a single call.`

What this means is that when you do:

```
$('#rep_user_id_'+userid).replaceWith(''+reputation);
```

It changes:

```
<div class="rep_user_id" id="rep_user_id_110">293</div>
//to
293
```

So the second time it fires the ajax it cannot find the id `rep_user_id`. The easiest way to solve this would be to change the innerHTML with `text()` (note: you can also use `hml()` but in this case `text()` works better because there are no html tags).

```
$('#rep_user_id_'+userid).text(reputation);
```

Comment: I think the value of the reputation variable is the entire HTML of the div.

Comment: That's not the problem, locrizak. The issue is not that I can't change an element multiple times, but that I can't change multiple elements with same id just once.